# Referencing a non static member with an instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want this class to render a grid each time it is instantiated, but I am getting the error, error

> CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member
>   `UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent(System.Type)'

So I instantiate an object of Renderer called Rend and set that equal to the non-static member but I am still getting the error? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have researched for several hours and still can't figure this out.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SetGrid : MonoBehaviour {

    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        Renderer Rend = GameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureScale = new Vector2 (x, y);

    }
}
```

Comment: The code sample provided doesn't compile. Please post a MVCE of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this script is part of your grid game object which also has a component of type `Renderer`.

The correct syntax to scale the texture of the `Renderer` is following:

```
public class SetGrid : MonoBehaviour {

    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        // Get a reference to the Renderer component of the game object.
        Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        // Scale the texture.
        rend.material.mainTextureScale = new Vector2 (x, y);
    }
}
```

---

The error message was thrown because you tried to call `GetComponent` on a **type** of `GameObject` and not an **instance** of `GameObject`. The script itself is already in the context of a `GameObject` meaning that you can just access a component with `GetComponent` from a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the Rend object, it's caused by the fact that the GetComponent method is non-static. That means you need to instantiate a GameObject object and use that one to call GetComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Change `GameObject.GetComponent` to `gameObject.GetComponent`, so that you're referencing the `gameObject` that this MonoBehaviour script belongs to.

Or you can even not use `gameObject.GetComponent` and just use `GetComponent` by itself.

See the [MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) inherited members for details.